# How to specify a literal in the Enumerate formal Specifier

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate

I have a subsection listing out 5 major targets, and I want the following subsections to specify the subpoints of each target. These subpoints should be labelled 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and so on in the first subsection, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, and on in the next and so on. Note that these are not sublists, they are disjoint lists connected to the prior list only due to their numbering.

The following works for giving numbers like 2.1, 2.2, ..., which is what I want. However, I **can't get this to work for sections 1.1, 1.2, ..., because soon as I write 1.1 in the format specifier**, the first 1 also gets read in as a counter.

```
\begin{enumerate}[2.1]
    \item First Point.
    \item Second Point.
    \item Third Point.
\end{enumerate}
```

Can someone help me specify **literal-1.counter-1** for the enumeration pattern.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```latex
\begin{enumerate}[{1}.1]
```

but there's a slicker way, if you want the first number to be the current subsection number. With this approach, even if you modify the order of the subsections, you won't need to manually change the numbers in the `enumerate` environments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment{subenumerate}
 {\begin{enumerate}[\arabic{subsection}.1]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{subenumerate}
\item Item
\item Item
\item Item
\end{subenumerate}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{subenumerate}
\item Item
\item Item
\item Item
\end{subenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I suggest to use `enumitem`, that gives much more control on lists.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{subenumerate}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic{subsection}.\arabic*]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{subenumerate}
\item Item
\item Item
\item Item
\end{subenumerate}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{subenumerate}
\item Item
\item Item
\item Item
\end{subenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]